# Disappearing threads in development, not production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using threads to split-off the individual (one thread per email) generation of emails (1-4 per web request). Everything works fine, if I don't thread. All is well also in production. But in development, only the first 1-2 emails is processed and the rest are never sent. No errors are raised, as is expected with threads, but again, this works perfectly in production.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

[UPDATE]
Using Rails 3.2.6

Comment: Which version of rails? after the request that triggers the sending of the emails are there other requests being handled by your app or none?

Comment: what webserver are you using? Can you show the code?

Comment: @FrederickCheung These are singular web requests, that individually may triggers 1-3 individually-threaded Actionmailer email deliveries. So yes, there will be subsequent requests, but once each thread finishes sending, the thread is complete.

Comment: @OscarDelBen Nginx. Which code is helpful? There aren't obvious errors (threads don't display errors) and the code runs perfectly in production, so not sure which code is problematic.

Comment: @CCole: It's perfectly possible to display errors occurring in threads. Just wrap the body in a `begin..rescue` block and print or log the exception in the rescue block.

Comment: @Confusion Tried that and its more complicated than that. In threads, the error will only be trapped if you trap and then direct to a new thread. Then you can output the error. Didn't try this for 2 reasons: 1) I didn't want to have to setup a subsequent thread, and 2) I think there is actually no error being generated (I suspect this).

Comment: Is your code changing in between requests in a way that would trigger the automatic code reloading while the threads are still running?

Comment: @FrederickCheung No, but where are you heading? In production, where its not class-reloading, all is fine. In development, where it is class-reloading, there is an issue. Are my threads being overwritten in some way?

Comment: Well if a class got unloaded while a thread was still using it I doubt anything good would happen.